# How to only allow access thru an IFRAME

Tags: apache, http, iframe, http-headers

I noticed the other day that Stack Overflow blocks HTTP requests from an IFRAME

```html
<IFRAME src="https://stackoverflow.com">
</IFRAME>
```

My question is: Where in the HTTP request header does it get the information that the request is coming from an IFRAME? I am actually interested in doing the opposite: Only accessible from an IFRAME while not accessible directly.

FYI: I have experience creating CORS/.htaccess policies (using Apache) and I can believe that the answer could easily be related to this. Again, what would I need to do to block direct requests but accept those from IFRAME s?

Comment: It's `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`, and it's your browser which recognizes the violation. The server cannot know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@f_puras 's comment led me to the

content-security-policy `frame-ancestors`

directive, the newer way to control frame content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors)